# xen server 6.2: lost a VM when moving?

Tags: xen

I have three servers in a HA group (Xen 6.2). I've been doing some firmware updates which require rebooting so I've been shuffling VMs around to minimize disruption. One of the VMs seems to have gotten unhappy when it was moved.

When it was migrated this error appeared:

```
Internal error: Object with type VM and id <UUID>/vbd.xvdb does not exist in xenopsd
```

Followed by:

```
There were no servers available to complete the specified operation
```

When all the servers are up and running - tried to restart said VM using XenCenter. Got this error message:

```
Object has been deleted.VDI:OpaqueRef:NULL (with an entry for each server)
```

Wondering if this is recoverable somehow... and how to avoid it in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW: to solve this I had to force a shutdown of the offending VM. Then I was able to restart it. Further attempts to migrate this VM have resulted in similar faults.

Comment: ethrbunny: did you try updating xen tools afther power cicle? that worked for me, the VM migrates fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to avoid it, but the following (quick and dirty) solutions work for me.

Solution 1:  Shutdown the machine, make a fast copy and start the copy.
After checking the copied vm you can delete the original machine.

Solution 2: Restart the xenserver where the vm was running on.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be related to a mounted CD/DVD ISO on the host. Dismount all and try again. We had this problem on the past with multiple versions of Xen Server.